# UICollectionView + iOS 7 / Xcode 5 = Assertion Failure

Tags: ios7, uicollectionview, xcode5, uncaught-exception

In my app there was a UICollectionView using flowLayout and it was working beautifully in iOS 6 but fails horribly in iOS 7.  As soon as I segue to the view containing my UICollectionView here's what happens:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _createPreparedSupplementaryViewForElementOfKind:atIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2903.2/UICollectionView.m:1401
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'the view returned from -collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath
(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader,<NSIndexPath: 0x145f3f50> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}) was not retrieved by calling -dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath: or is nil'
(<UICollectionReusableView: 0x145f9400; frame = (0 0; 320 20); layer = <CALayer: 0x145f90c0>>)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When I updated to iOS 7 I ran into this.  The problem ended up being that you shouldn't be so explicit with your dataSource.  If you have the following, remove it:

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer @ZaBlanc, thank you!  Any idea what changed from iOS 6 to 7?  [The iOS 7 API Diffs](https://t.co/vuiz2TaU3r) don't show anything but additions to UICollectionView

Answer (score 6):

It will crash if you return `nil` in this function:

```
- (UICollectionReusableView*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Basically, the only reason you would have to return `nil` is if the "kind" `NSString` is not a type you expect. In that case, just delete that object in the interface builder. I had this same crash because my collection view had a footer in the interface builder but I was not calling the `registerNib` code (as bneely described above) to set up a footer. I'd get to the `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` and return nil because it was a kind I was not expecting.(which is guaranteed to cause the crash).

Answer (score 1):

You need to register a UINib with your UICollectionView instance:

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"YourNibNameWithoutExtension" bundle:nil];
[collectionView registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"YourReuseIdentifier"];
```

And create all of your UICollectionViewCell instances via `-[UICollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:]`.

This comment in Apple's UICollectionView.h explains the requirement:

```
// The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Comment: Thanks @bneely, I was already registering nibs (and classes initially) but it turns out ZaBlanc's answer fixed the mystery crash.  Don't ask me how/why because nothing in UICollectionView was really deprecated in the iOS7 API Diffs.

Answer (score 1):

I've got this problem, as solved

I think you could check have you check the Section Header
in IB Collection View -> Accessories -> Section Header

Answer (score 1):

I received this by forgetting to set my class to the correct type in interface builder and not wiring up and outlets

Comment: Aha... something like this happened too! Thank you for this comment, it made me check my newly created reusable view.. now the internal inconsistency exception makes sense! :D

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because your collection has a header.
I got that after adding a header in IB. Remove the header or check the Delegate for header options

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have set collection view datasource and delegate. In my case this error was being thrown because of it.