# Assertion Failure - CollectionView inside UITableViewCell with Auto-Layout and custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a rather complex view layout:

```
ViewController
- TableViewController inside ContainerView (as child view controller)
  - TableViewCell which holds UICollectionView with subclassed (custom) FlowLayout
```

When trying to add a `UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader` supplementary view through my subclassed FlowLayout, I'm getting the following error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[MyCollectionView _createPreparedSupplementaryViewForElementOfKind:atIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UICollectionView.m:1305
```

Tried solution proposed here: [UICollectionView + iOS 7 / Xcode 5 = Assertion Failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034098/uicollectionview-ios-7-xcode-5-assertion-failure)
but without any luck. I am using Dynamic Auto-Layout Height for my TableViewCells and am wondering if that could have to do w/ it...

Anyone have an idea or could point me in the right direction to troubleshoot? Thanks!

Comment: I found this
[solutions][1]
[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33253109/ios-error-assertion-failure-in-uicollectionview-layoutsublayersoflayer-in-io , it works fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh.. I figured out what was causing the `Assertion Failure` in my code. Due to my complex nesting of CollectionViews inside of TableViewCells, I wasn't setting the CollectionView's `dataSource` property before accessing its layout...