# ios error Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView layoutSublayersOfLayer:] in ios 7

Tags: objective-c

I am using collection view and getting a crash in ios 7 but it's working fine above 7. Getting crash after the line: 
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

the error message here:

*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UIView.m:8794

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. UICollectionView's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'

Answer (score 0):

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still
>   required after executing -layoutSubviews. UICollectionView's
>   implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'

This error has very useful information. Ensure that, in your collection view, you are calling `layoutSubviews` on `super` and there is no code after that.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
  // Your Custom Code

  [super layoutSubviews]; // No code after this and this is called last
}
```

You can try creating a custom `UICollectionView` and enforcing call to `layoutSubviews` on `super` something like this:

```
@interface MyCollectionView : UICollectionView

@end

@implentation MyCollectionView

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    // Your Custom Code

    [super layoutSubviews];
}

@end
```

Comment: not working.  collection view not creating view in ios 7 without using "layoutIfNeeded" but above 7 working well. I think it needs to create layout when I'm dismissing the next viewController and coming back to collection view

Comment: Can you please show some code how you are implementing it and the line of crash.

Comment: - (IBAction)backButtonAction:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
} getting the crash when I'm trying to go back. Actually I'm opening a view controller which having some descriptions on collectionCell click. but when I'm trying to go back its crashing

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the code via gitHub link or something. I could take a look and respond back. Hard to tell with such short description.